# Replace a file with the same name in zip

Tags: c#, zip

I have a code that creates or adds files to a zip archive specified. What I can't find is the option to replace file in zip if I'm trying to add another one with same name.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (oflFilesToZip.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string[] files = oflFilesToZip.FileNames;
            bool zipExists = File.Exists(zipPath);

            ZipArchive zip;
            if (zipExists)
            {
                zip = ZipFile.Open(zipPath, ZipArchiveMode.Update);
            }
            else zip = ZipFile.Open(zipPath, ZipArchiveMode.Create);

            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                zip.CreateEntryFromFile(file, Path.GetFileName(file), CompressionLevel.Optimal);                   
            }
            zip.Dispose();

        }
    }
```

Is there any method for that, or do I have to for example manually open the zip, get all entries and check one by one if the filename I'm adding already exists within the zip?

Comment: Given the nature of Zip files I would expect to delete the old entry and add a new one. Replace would only be a helper to perform the two operations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`CreateEntryFromFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485720(v=vs.110).aspx) will add another one if there was already an entry with that name:

> an entry with the specified name (entryName) already exists in the
>   archive, a second entry is created with an identical name

So you have to [`Delete`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchiveentry.delete(v=vs.110).aspx) it from the archieve before you add it.

```
foreach (string file in files)
{
    ZipArchiveEntry oldEntry = zip.GetEntry(file);
    if(oldEntry != null) oldEntry.Delete();   
    zip.CreateEntryFromFile(file, Path.GetFileName(file), CompressionLevel.Optimal);        
}
```